# Win XP: Disable guest account on certain period of time?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, user-accounts

Is it possible to only allow guest account for example between 8AM-5PM only?
Beyond that time, guest account should be disabled and not be allowed.
Ideally logging-off users and preventing them from logging-in.

Comment: What version of XP?

Comment: @soandos SP2 but I can upgrade to SP3 if needed

Comment: I mean professional?

Comment: @soandos Yes it's professional

Comment: In group policy you can set the time

Comment: You might want to look at something like [this](http://www.group-policy.com/ref/policy/2779/Terminate_session_when_time_limits_are_reached). Too tired to do more sorry.